# Connect to Microsoft access database from .net core version 6.0 project

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, .net-6.0, jet-ef-provider

I get error that error when I try to use EntityFrameworkCore.Jet with my .net core 6 app

> Method 'AppendIdentityWhereCondition' in type 'EntityFrameworkCore.Jet.Update.Internal.JetUpdateSqlGenerator' from assembly 'EntityFrameworkCore.Jet, Version=3.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation.

Comment: EntityFrameworkCore.Jet 3.1.1 is compatible only with EF Core 3.1.x. Read github readme page.

Comment: I am upgrading my code from .net core 3.1 to 6.0, but I can't find compatible version from EntityFrameworkCore.Jet, can you advice what should I do in that case

Comment: 1) Create issue in `EntityFrameworkCore.Jet` github reprository 2) fork latest version and become EF Core provider developer. I see that latest sources are almost ready to EF Core 5

Comment: I don't find any information about `EntityFrameworkCore.Jet` can be supported in .Net 6, But the readme in this [github](https://github.com/bubibubi/EntityFrameworkCore.Jet)  said :Any questions about how to use `EntityFrameworkCore.Jet` can be ask on `StackOverflow` using the `jet-ef-provider` and `entity-framework-core` tags.